# UWP Tile Image Stretch and Fill

Tags: c#, uwp, tile

I am trying to implement a tile with the a thumbnail completely covers the tile. But there is some margin. How can I remove that and make it stretch and fill the entire tile?

[image: TileMedium]

Another question is that, in addition to the image problem, in the `TileMedium`, the text is not showing up. I am expecting it to appear at the left bottom. How should I fix it?

[image: TileWide]

My last question is, although I have implemented it in the code, `TileLarge` doesn't appear as an option when I right click the tile to adjust its size.

This is the code:

```
    public static void UpdateTile(Music music)
    {
        string uri = Thumbnail.Path;
        var tileContent = new TileContent()
        {
            Visual = new TileVisual()
            {
                TileMedium = new TileBinding()
                {
                    Branding = TileBranding.None,
                    Content = new TileBindingContentAdaptive()
                    {
                        Children =
                        {
                            new AdaptiveImage() { Source = uri },
                        }
                    }
                },
                TileWide = new TileBinding()
                {
                    Branding = TileBranding.None,
                    Content = new TileBindingContentAdaptive()
                    {
                        Children =
                        {
                            new AdaptiveImage()
                            {
                                Source = uri
                            },
                            new AdaptiveText()
                            {
                                Text = music.Name,
                                HintStyle = AdaptiveTextStyle.Title
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                TileLarge = new TileBinding()
                {
                    Branding = TileBranding.None,
                    Content = new TileBindingContentAdaptive()
                    {
                        Children =
                        {
                            new AdaptiveImage()
                            {
                                Source = uri
                            },
                            new AdaptiveGroup()
                            {
                                Children =
                                {
                                    new AdaptiveSubgroup()
                                    {
                                        Children =
                                        {
                                            new AdaptiveText()
                                            {
                                                Text = music.Name,
                                                HintStyle = AdaptiveTextStyle.Caption
                                            },
                                            new AdaptiveText()
                                            {
                                                Text = music.Artist,
                                                HintStyle = AdaptiveTextStyle.CaptionSubtle
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        // Create the tile notification
        var tileNotification = new TileNotification(tileContent.GetXml());

        // And send the notification to the primary tile
        tileUpdater.Update(tileNotification);
    }
}
```

Sorry for so many questions. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Q1:Image problem

If you want to fill the tile,you can set the image to the BackgroundImage instead of AdaptiveImage.

> Q2:Show text at the left bottom in TileMedium.

You can set Displayname and Branding in TileMedium.In this case,the text will appear at the left bottom.

```
TileMedium = new TileBinding()
{
    DisplayName = music.Name,
    Branding = TileBranding.Name,
    Content = new TileBindingContentAdaptive()
    {
        BackgroundImage = new TileBackgroundImage()
        {
            Source = uri
        },
        Children =
        {
            ......
        }
    }
},
```

> Q3:TileLarge

Go to **Package.appxmanifest->Visual Assets->Large Tile**.Select Large Tile option in Display Settings.

Comment: Thank you! I have another quick question about the tile. How can I resume the Tile  (from the album art back to the logo) when my app is not running?

Comment: When you close your app,you can update tile(from album art back to the logo) in Suspending event in App.xaml.cs.